# Can I update all records with using JSON_ARRAYAGG?

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-8.0

I have two tables;
users and messages.

users table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Mike |
| 2 | John |

message table is like below

| id | title | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAAAAA | 1 |
| 2 | BBBBBB | 1 |
| 3 | CCCCCC | 2 |

I have to add `titles` column to users table.
in this column, the record value should be an array of message titles associated with each member.
i.e.)

| id | name | titles |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mike | ["AAAAAA", "BBBBBB"] |
| 2 | John | ["CCCCCC"] |

I know this is denormalizing and meaningless way of holding data, but
this is just a hypothetical situation.

In that situation, I added json column called `titles` and created the following query in order to update all records of users with the array of title.

```
UPDATE 
`users`
SET 
`users`.`titles` = 
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(`messages`.`title`)
FROM `users`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `messages`
ON `messages.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
GROUP BY `members`.`id`
```

Here I used `JSON_ARRAYAGG` to create an array.
when I ran it, I received an syntax error.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 10
```

What was wrong in this query?
Could you teach me how can I fix it and how can I achieve what I wan to do?

mysql version is 8.0.24.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: MySQL does not use FROM clause in UPDATE syntax. Study Reference Manual for correct synax, see Multiple-table UPDATE. Use aggregate subquery as datasource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE users
NATURAL JOIN ( 
    SELECT user_id id, JSON_ARRAYAGG(title) titles
    FROM messages
    GROUP BY 1 
    ) subquery
SET users.titles = subquery.titles;
```

Of course the column `titles` must be added into the `users` table structure before.

LEFT joining not needed - newly created column contains NULL in all rows already. But if you update existing data, including for those rows whose value must be cleared then use `NATURAL LEFT JOIN`.